# SQL statement to get $0 if the customer has no billing from any specific year

Tags: sql

I am trying to find the average billing amount per year from 2019 to 2021 for every customer, and I want to return $0 if the customer has no billing from any specific year. I tried doing a left join but unfortunately it does not give the result I need. In the table below, how do I return $0 for customer_id 1 since the year for 2021 does not exist. Thanks.

billing table:

| customer_id | billing_id | created_date | billing_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | id_11 | 2019-06-21 | 100 |
| 1 | id_12 | 2020-05-11 | 126 |
| 1 | id_13 | 2019-12-28 | 86 |
| 2 | id_21 | 2019-12-28 | 28 |
| 2 | id_22 | 2020-12-28 | 56 |
| 2 | id_23 | 2021-12-28 | 26 |

Here is my incorrect query:

```
Select a.customer_id,
       extract(year from a.created_date),
       avg(a.billing_amount)
from billing as a
left join billing as b
    on a.customer_id = b.customer_id 
where a.created_date between '2019-01-01' and '2021-12-31'
group by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **It was edit for add the links**

You can try using **WITH**

First the DDL statements

```
create database test;
create table billing (
  billing_id int,
  customer_id int,
  created_date date,
  billing_amount int    
);
alter table billing add constraint pk_billing primary key (billing_id);
create table customer (
  customer_id int,
  name varchar
)
alter table customer add constraint pk_customer primary key (customer_id);
alter table billing add constraint fk_customer foreign key (customer_id) references customer (customer_id);
```

Now the DML statements

```
insert into customer values (1,'Client 1'), (2,'Client 2');
insert into billing values (11,1,'2019-06-21',100),(12,1,'2020-05-11',126),(13,1,'2019-12-28',86),(21,2,'2019-12-28',28),(22,2,'2020-12-28',56),(23,2,'2021-12-28',26);
```

And finally the DQL query with **WITH**

```
with customer_year as (select distinct a.customer_id,vy."Year"
from billing a,(select distinct extract(year from a.created_date) as "Year"
from billing as a
where a.created_date between '2019-01-01' and '2021-12-31') vy
order by customer_id,vy."Year")
select cy.customer_id,cy."Year",
(select case when avg(a.billing_amount) is null then 0 else avg(a.billing_amount) end 
from billing a 
where a.customer_id = cy.customer_id and 
extract(year from a.created_date) = cy."Year")
from customer_year cy;
```

This answer is for **PostgreSQL**

For **MySQL** or **MariaDB** change something in the **DDL** and the **DQL**

You can check in:
[PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1f30f4bb03cd359c8bbc8a917f1e199d)

[MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a832f2b53771b0ff44e40a57a4af8ed0)

[MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=a832f2b53771b0ff44e40a57a4af8ed0)